# Trying to add tool tip to every image on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, drawimage

I am trying to add tool tip to every image I draw on the `JPanel`. But each time a new Image is added, the tool tip text gets over written because I am using `this.setToolTipText(text);` for every image.

As seen in the image, the second traffic light image shows tool tip that reads traffic light 3 because that was the last image added.

Can someone please tell me another way to add unique tool tips? I searched for possible solutions but could not find any.

[image]

```
//Drawing the blockage on the road
g.drawImage(blockageImage, bestMatchRUnit.getX(), bestMatchRUnit.getY(), 5, 5, this); 
this.setToolTipText("Blockage: " + blockageIndex); //setting the tooltip
blockageIndex++;
```

Comment: Be sure to review the preview of the message before posting it.  In this case, the image disappeared when the embedded marker for it was formatted as code.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). 3) Why not display the image(s) in a `JLabel`(s) and add the tool tip to the label?

Comment: Don't change the state of any component from within any paint method

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to display a JLabel with an ImageIcon on your panel. Then you can add individual tool tip messages to each JLabel.

Or, the other approach is to override the `getToolTipText(...)` method of your JPanel. Then you will need to keep an ArrayList of a custom Object that contains two pieces of data:

1. the Rectangle to represent the size/location of each image
2. the tool tip for the image

Then in the `getToolTipText(...)` method you need to iterate through the ArrayList to find the image that contains the mouse point and the you need to return the tool tip message.